# Multiple PSQL gems causing problems

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, postgresql, postgres.app

I have a rails 3.2.8 site that was configured to use Postgres.App. The gem it was using was pg (0.12.2) It was working fine. I wanted to build another app and so set everything up as with the other app but I was getting this error:

```
/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/pg-0.17.1/lib/pg.rb:4:in `require': dlopen(/Users/********/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/pg-0.17.1/lib/pg_ext.bundle, 9): Library not loaded: @executable_path/../lib/libssl.1.0.0.dylib (LoadError) Referenced from: /Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/MacOS/lib/libpq.dylib Reason: image not found - /Users/***********/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/pg-0.17.1/lib/pg_ext.bundle
```

The gem in use here was pg (0.17.1) and I thought the discrepancy might be causing the problem so I uninstalled and reinstalled the gems. Now neither of them work and I get the same error message for both apps.

The Postgres.App version is 9.2.4.1

Answer (score 0):

The solution that worked was to upgrade Postgres.App to the latest version, which I did by simply downloading the newest version and saving it over the top of the old one. Apparently there were some bugs in the earlier version. It now works fine for me.